# Why do people NOT put empty lines before spoiler paragraphs?

Tags: discussion, markdown

I noticed a puzzling trend lately, editing a lot of TFA content (since it contains spoiler blocks).

A lot of people format their spoiler blocks with NO empty line after preceding text, like this:

```
I'm talking about this secret stuff
>! my Spoiler
```

as opposed to:

```
I'm talking about this secret stuff

>! my Spoiler
```

Is there a reason this is done? Is that a method I should be using to (my normal way - due to stylistic readability preference - is to always precede quote blocks, including spoiler blocks, with an empty line)?

Or merely random preference with no effect and done as personal preference?

(side note: Not sure if this is unique to spoiler blocks or all quote blocks - I never noticed the trend before with quote blocks but doesn't mean it wasn't there)

Comment: Just my opinion I prefer your style, makes it easier to edit if nothing else. I just think we're getting a lot of users who aren't familiar with writing stylistically good questions.  Plus, the spoiler markup is notoriously buggy, no need to tempt fate :)

Comment: Doesn't the output look identical for both possibilities?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest that the reason is at least partly related to the official [Markdown Editing Help](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers) page:

When a user clicks on the advanced help link, the spoiler tag demo/example itself that pops up on the instructions page shows *no spacing* between the non-spoiler and spoiler segement.

[image: Screenshot of the “Spoilers” section of the help page.]

Comment: Thanks, @JakeGould. :) Was trying to add that example in.

Answer (score 9):

**There is literally no difference.**

The example below shows two spoiler blocks – one with a newline, one without. The output HTML is the same in both cases. There is no difference between the two.

As such, I think it comes down to personal preference. There’s no “better” way of doing it.

I prefer having the empty line there, because I think it looks nicer, and I use some Markdown parsers which don’t start a blockquote unless it’s preceded by a newline – but it’s not a strong preference. Don’t overthink it.

---

### Example

**Markdown source:**

```
I’ve written a paragraph
>! and there isn’t a newline in the Markdown source.



I've written another paragraph

>! And although you can’t see it, there’s a newline in the Markdown source.
```

**HTML output:**

```
<p>I’ve written a paragraph</p>

<blockquote class="spoiler">
  <p> and there isn’t a newline in the Markdown source.</p>
</blockquote>

<p></p>

<p>I've written another paragraph</p>

<blockquote class="spoiler">
  <p> And although you can’t see it, there’s a newline in the Markdown source.</p>
</blockquote>
```

**Rendered output:**

I’ve written a paragraph

> and there isn’t a newline in the Markdown source.

I've written another paragraph

> And although you can’t see it, there’s a newline in the Markdown source.

Answer (score 1):

The only situation I can think of in which it *would* make a difference is when your question/answer is using **bullet points** or a **numbered list**.

## Without empty line:

- In film #1 we learn

  > spoiler #1
- In film #2 we learn

  > spoiler #2
- In film #3 we learn

  > spoiler #3

## With empty line:

- In film #1 we learn

> spoiler #1

- In film #2 we learn

> spoiler #2

- In film #3 we learn

> spoiler #3

You'll notice that, if you're making a list with bullets/numbers, it looks neater to have **no empty line**. See [What are the things that “The Force Awakens” borrowed/parallel from “A New Hope?”](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111224/what-are-the-things-that-the-force-awakens-borrowed-parallel-from-a-new-hope) for an example of how nice it looks *without* an empty line. 
<sub>I believe I was the one who made that edit, since lists become much harder to read and follow if there *is* an empty line.</sub>

---

This also applies to normal blockquotes; this is not specific to spoiler tags.

Comment: When I do bullets, I simply prefix the blockquotes with 3 spaces: `   >`  and that fixes the alignment :)